# Angular: Routing between pages using condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to route between pages using basic `if` condition in Angular.

```
  GoToHome() {
    if(this.router.url=='/chat'){
      console.log(this.router.url)
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['people']);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the route chat isn't really correct, there are many pages in chat (chat\x , chat\y and many others) I want that it will work for all the pages in chat, but right now it doesn't work. If I write a specific route like chat\x it does work, but only for x. Is there a way to do it for all?

Answer (score 0):

you can read and check Guards. Read about CanActivate method, maybe it will help you?

Answer (score 0):

RouteGuards might do a better job of handling the redirects as per your requirement.

But a quick workaround would be to do a [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the URL and compare for the `chat` part. Try the following

```js
if(((this.router.url).split('/')[1]) === 'chat') {
  // proceed
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Would be great if you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As other had said, best solution is to use Angular Guard https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3.

Anyway to resolve your problem you can use **startsWith()** function which determines whether a string begins with the characters of a specified string.

```
GoToHome() {
    if((this.router.url).startsWith('/chat'){
      console.log(this.router.url)
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['people']);
    }
  }
```